# Android: ListView con SearchView despues de filtrar me muestra la lista vacia

Tags: java, android, listview, filtro, searchview

Tengo un listView de elementos en los cuales son cargados mediante un Adapter.
Luego, agregue un SearchView para poder filtrar esos datos.

**Filtra correctamente**, pero el problema surge **despues de borrar ese filtro la lista me aparece en blanco** como muestro en capturas.

Solamente al volver a cargar el fragmento me lista nuevamente los datos.

¿Como puedo hacer para que al borrar el filtro me liste nuevamente la lista original de datos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto partes importantes del fragmento y el adaptador.

**Fragmento**:

```
public FragmentListarAlumnos() {   }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listar_alumnos, container, false);
    list = view.findViewById(R.id.listviewAlumnos);
    txtBuscar= view.findViewById(R.id.txtBuscarAlumno);

    if(tieneConexionInternet()) { 
        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fabalumnos);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), AltaAlumno.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        adaptador = new AdaptadorPersonas(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), persons);
        list.setAdapter(adaptador);
       
        mostrarDatos(url);
        txtBuscar.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    }      
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    adaptador.filtrado(newText);
    return false;
}

public void mostrarDatos(String url) {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            persons.clear();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String sucess=jsonObject.getString("sucess");
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("personas");
                if (sucess.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject object= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id= object.getString("personas_id");
                        String dni = object.getString("dni");
                        String apellido = object.getString("apellido");
                        String nombres = object.getString("nombres");
                        String estado = object.getString("estado");
                        String usuario_id = object.getString("usuario_id");

                        Personas personas = new Personas(id, dni, apellido, nombres, 
                                estado, usuario_id,);
                        persons.add(personas);
                        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

**Adaptador**

```
public class AdaptadorPersonas extends ArrayAdapter<Personas> {

Context context;
List<Personas> arrayListPersons;
List<Personas> listaOriginal;

public AdaptadorPersonas(@NonNull Context context, List<Personas>arrayListPersons) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_personas, arrayListPersons);
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayListPersons=arrayListPersons;
    listaOriginal = new ArrayList<>();
    listaOriginal.addAll(arrayListPersons);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView (int position, @NonNull View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_personas, null, true);
    TextView tvDNI= view.findViewById(R.id.tvDniPersona);
    TextView tvpersona = view.findViewById(R.id.tvpersona);
    TextView tvEstado = view.findViewById(R.id.tvEstadoPersona);

    tvDNI.setText("DNI: "+arrayListPersons.get(position).getDni());
    tvpersona.setText(arrayListPersons.get(position).getApellido()+" "+arrayListPersons.get(position).getNombres());
    return view;
}

public void  filtrado(final String txtBuscar) {
    int longitud= txtBuscar.length();
    if (longitud == 0) {
        arrayListPersons.clear();
        arrayListPersons.addAll(listaOriginal);
    }
    else {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            List <Personas> coleccion=arrayListPersons.stream()
                    .filter(i -> i.getApellido().toLowerCase().contains(txtBuscar.toLowerCase()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            arrayListPersons.clear();
            arrayListPersons.addAll(coleccion);
        }
        else {
           for (Personas p: listaOriginal){
               if(p.getApellido().toLowerCase().contains(txtBuscar.toLowerCase())) {
                   arrayListPersons.add(p);
               }
           }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}//fin filtrado
```

}

Comment: ¿A caso no te estás olvidando de limpiar la lista antes de entrar al for?

Comment: Hola Mateo, no. ¿O en que parte decis?

Comment: @Mateo lo está limpiando antes del `try`, ahora con respecto al post, ¿Se debe cargar la grilla cuando presionas en la **x** del `SearchView ` o cuando borras una letra con el `teclado`?

Comment: claro, se debe cargar la grilla completa luego de presionar la x del SearchView o cuando borro pero eso no me funciona. Me muestra la lista en blanco.

Comment: @Franqo Bálsamo me refería en el adaptador.